# How to create a Concrete WSDL in tibco

Tags: soap, wsdl, tibco

I have created a WSDL (Abstract) for a SOAP web service. I have to use this WSDL in the SOAP Request Reply.

But in the Service port of SOAPRequestReply, I have to specify a Concrete WSDL. So if there is any way to create a Concrete WSDL.

Let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Service (using service pallets) with your WSDL(Abstract), you will have to setup the operation(s) and transport type (HTTP or JMS). 
Once you have done that, go to the WSDL tab. You should be able to save a Concrete WSDL out.

Hope this help :P